# Custom Google's Scope for Mobile Client Access service on IBM Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

How configure the Google's `Scope` when using **Mobile Client Access** service on **Bluemix**?

I need the `email` address, but seems like only `profile` is configured by default.

When using the Passport Google Strategy directly this configurations goes in `passport.authenticate()`'s call like below:

```
var authRouter = express.Router();

app.use('/auth', authRouter);

authRouter.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', { 
    scope : ['profile', 'email']
}));
```

Contextualization: I'm protecting a web application exactly like Anton Aleksandrov have written in his post [here](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2016/07/protect-web-apps-with-mobile-client-access/).

Comment: Hey you, if you like this question, please vote for a solution here: https://ibmcloud.ideas.aha.io/ideas/IDEA-I-1887

Answer (score 0):

The identity token that MCA returns doesn't appear to include an email in the response at this time. I will ask the MCA team about adding this feature in the future.

Comment: Hi Joe, thank you for your answer, but this is exactly what I already know, i.e. I'm sure that the MCA ask for profile Scope only. How can I help you about asking for the MCA team to introduce the capability of choose the Google's Scopes?

Comment: I have asked the MCA team about adding this feature. However it is important to note that even if the “email” scope is added to the request, it doesn’t mean user will allow us to access it. Basically MCA asks for a set of scopes, but the user can select which scopes to allow. e.g. MCA asks for basic_profile and email, but the user can choose to allow basic_profile only (so email scope is not 100% reliable).

Comment: Also, you can submit your idea here: https://ibmcloud.ideas.aha.io/?category=6322429981421470858

Comment: thanks joe, idea submitted:
https://ibmcloud.ideas.aha.io/ideas/IDEA-I-1887